# Apache/Wamp/php issue? Chrome showing closing php tag ?>

Tags: php, arrays, google-chrome

I have a probably basic but still weird issue - Chrome won't show array properly and displays closing php tag. I'm sure i'm making some very basic error somewhere. I tried enclosing both array keys and values with single and double quotes, changing ending semicolon to colon, but nothing works.

Here is the test page code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<?php

$beatles = array(
    "John" => "vocals",
    "Paul" => "bass",
    "George" => "guitar",
    "Ringo" => "drums",
);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the output in Chrome:

```
"vocals", "Paul" => "bass", "George" => "guitar", "Ringo" => "drums", ); ?>**
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the file extension ?

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski Interesting, but that wouldn't explain why there is an output in Chrome. It's more likely apache doesn't pass the request to php.

Comment: Apache is not executing php for your file.

Comment: Is php installed? Also be sure to save the file as .php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, make sure that you are accessing localhost and not the actual file on your computer.  Your URL should say "localhost/yourfile.php".

Then, check and make sure that the file extension that you're loading ends in .php

Lastly, verify that Apache is setup to use PHP on .php files.  You can verify this inside of the httpd.conf.

To do this,

1. Left click on the Wamp icon in the bottom right tray of your computer
2. Apache
3. Left click httpd.conf
4. Search for `<IfModule mime_module>`
5. Verify that it has this line:
   `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

Comment: Thanks! This line was commented out (?) for some strange reason... I Uncommented and it started working properly. Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure PHP is working on your server? Have you tested something else? Try the below given code and and see what happens?

```
<?php echo time(); ?>
```

Comment: Nope. Sems that the PHP parser is not working... WAMP icon in the tray is green, I see all 3 services running but something is messed up.

Answer (score 1):

i think you save file with .html extension , and your file is not php file , you must write your code in file with php extension. and print_r your array for show array values.

Answer (score 1):

This code in a PHP file will show nothing, in html will not work. You should rename this file to fileName.php

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one thing i am getting in mind and that is the extension of the file is not php. Check the extension of the file , if it's not php try to save the code into php.

Comment: :) Nopw. I am a noob but not really that much of a noob